# Can I add 1 to everything before doing boxcox transformation because boxcox doesn't deal with zeros?

Tags: data-transformation, zero-inflation

The values of my outcome variable range from 0 to 2 and my data is zero inflated (See histogram below). 0 signifies almost no mental health symptoms and 2 signifies moderate to high symptoms. My sample size is around ~11000 and sampled 5 times over a 3 year period (with missing values for some people and some time points of course).

Since my data is zero inflated (children tend not to have too many mental health problems), the residuals from my linear mixed model are not normally distributed. I tried rank inverse and log transformation but it didn't change much. When I tried Box Cox however (from the MASS package), the residuals look much better.

Boxcox doesn't handle zeros though, so I added 1 to everything before transforming (the range therefore now is 1 to 3). Is this okay statistically speaking? I want to make sure I haven't done anything drastically wrong.

[image]

And here's the histogram after boxcox transformation

[image]

Comment: [You don't need normally distributed residuals.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5447/1352) Don't Box-Cox transform.

Comment: @StephanKolassa can you elaborate please? Isn't that one of the assumptions of a linear mixed effects model?

Comment: Is the outcome variable discrete or continuous? The statement "2 signifies moderate to high symptoms" suggests that it might be discrete ordinal (with values 0, 1 or 2).

Comment: It's a continuous variable (0-2 because it's a mean of a bunch of variables, each of which is ansewered on a 3 point likert scale [0, 1, 2 and the scores assigned to each value]), as are my predictors.

Comment: No, that is one of those pieces of "common knowledge" that are simply false, but apparently hard to eradicate. What you want is a normal distribution of *parameter estimates*. If residuals are normal, that helps, but the various limit theorems typically kick in with even quite low sample sizes. What you might want to look at are specific models for zero inflation, like a zero-inflated gamma or similar.

Comment: I've tried running glmer with family=Gamma but the model keeps giving convergence warnings, and adding `control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5))` didn't help

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for multilevel models with longitudinal data and a zero inflated outcome variable (I have three random effects, participant ID, site, and familyID so need an MLM)

Comment: If your outcome value has distinct values 0 1 2 then its marginal distribution consists of 3 spikes and any goal of a normal distribution is impossible to achieve, even roughly, as well as irrelevant., both for the outcome itself and also for residuals. Conversely, if you have somehow measured outcomes bounded by 0 and 2 then the same is true for different reasons.  We need more clarity on the outcome.  For example, a histogram would help.

Comment: Good point. The data is a mean of three values, so it is not discrete and doesn't have spikes at those values. I've added the histogram to the description. Would any other information be helpful?

Comment: The outcome is clearly bounded and there seems to be some discreteness.  Applying Box-Cox really is misconceived here.  It was never intended for bounded outcomes. You don't say what power you used but if you added 1 first, then even say $\ln (y + 1)$ for $0 \le y \le 2$ is almost straight and can't change skewness (distribution shape, more generally) that much, as your results show, and even if it could, it's at most skewness of residuals that is a slightly bigger deal.

Comment: I wouldn't call this zero-inflated.  I don't know enough for mixed models to know whether they can match the repeated measures flavour of your data adequately. In terms of your question, I can't see that you need to transform,  or that your transform is well justified or successful.  The question of how best to analyse these data deserves a different thread, in my view.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll create a new thread

Comment: But do you mind explaining why boxcox or Yeo-Johnson are not appropriate for bounded data @NickCox?

Comment: It's at least implicit in the original context that the domain considered is positive random variables, with some small print on the side. Otherwise the Box-Cox family of transformations doesn't make full sense. I've seen contexts where e.g. a power of [0, 1] can help because it also lies in the same interval but the goal here of getting closer to normality  doesn't convince with your data.

Comment: For cox read Cox and for box read Box everywhere. I am sensitive on this very small point. (Not even a relative, but still sensitive.)

Comment: *Pace* @NickCox, Box-Cox transformations can work just fine for bounded variables--boundedness does not automatically preclude their effectiveness.  However, this one is obviously discrete, has many true zeros, and the specific values appear to have no inherent meaning anyway (that is, it might best be considered an ordinal variable).  These all suggest that if any re-expression is going to help in any kind of analysis, it's unlikely to be a Box-Cox transformation.

Comment: I'd assert that there are in the OP's terms many true 2s in the data too, for what that's worth. That is, there isn't a transformation evident that is likely to transform the interval [0, 2] to a better space to work in. (I did acknowledge that powers can help on [0, 1].  which I have found  in my own work, so I am not in denial that Box-Cox can help, just in denial for the project and data discussed here.)

Comment: But all that implies that dividing by 2 might help!

Comment: For now I closed this as a duplicate of your new thread, but for the future, it is better to edit your question (including new/better title) than asking a new question! That way comments are preserved, for instance.